# How can I programmatically create a HTML comment in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html

Consider this snippet:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]—>
```

I have access to the `Page` object. So I can do something like this:

```
Page.Header.Controls.Add(new HtmlGenericControl())
```

How am I able to insert the above snippet to the ASP.NET Page's Header or Body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems hacky and there's probably a nicer solution, but this seems to work:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Literal comment = new Literal();
    comment.Text = @"<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src='//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js'></script><![endif]-->";
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(comment);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use page.clientscript.add("pageload",'')

Comment: The ClientScriptManager has no Method called "Add"